# Backbonejs and Zepto error after saving: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in 1

Tags: backbone.js, zepto

In my Backbone app I am able to list records, click in one record to see details, everything fine.

However, when I change a model and call save() method I get the error below. The data is saved in the backend but the Collection do not get the update.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in 1
_.extend.setbackbone.js:205
_.extend.save.options.successbackbone.js:300
ajaxSuccesszepto.js:881
$.ajax.xhr.onreadystatechangezepto.js:1085
```

Any hints?

tkx
Wils

Comment: Ooops! Fixed! The problem was on the backend response. If you are running in the same issue make sure the response is properly JSON.

Comment: You need to define the ID field in the backbone: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-id

Answer (score 3):

I ran in to this same problem recently. Turned out I had my json data returned with quotes around it, from the server. Once I fixed that, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because instead of setting the AJAX dataType to `json` it was set to `text`.

Answer (score 0):

The returned data is wrapped with quotes. Just parse the data via parseJSON and use it.

```
var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(jsondata, function (index, file) {
  //your code goes here                     
});
```